# How do I find out if an object can be Invoke()'d?

Tags: c#, events, invoke

Consider the following class:

```
public class Event<T>
{
    public delegate void Handler<t>(t msg);
    private event Handler<T> E;

    public void connect(Delegate handler) {
        E += delegate(T msg) {
            object target = handler.Target;

            if (Invokable(target) {
                target.BeginInvoke(handler, new object[] { msg });
            }
        };

    }

    public void emit(T msg) {
        if ( E != null ) {
            E(msg);
        }
    }

    private static bool Invokable(object o) {
                // magic
    }
}
```

How do I implement `Invokable()`, and what else do I need for this code to compile? The only other problem that I know of is the `target.BeginInvoke` call, since target is `object`.

Comment: What is the `Invokable` method supposed to tell about the object `o` (it is a static method, so it cannot access anything else)?

Comment: why do you reinvent delegates?

Comment: @Tomas: whether or not `o` is a Form, because then I need thread safety magic.

Comment: Surely this will only work for WinForms controls? You wouldn't be passing a Dispatcher through to this would you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to Invoke a System.Windows.Forms.Control

```
static bool Invokable(object o) {
  bool res = false;
  if(o is System.Windows.Forms.Control) {
   res = ((System.Windows.Forms.Control)o).InvokeRequired;
 }
 return res;
}
```